# Homeomorphic Spaces in Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces.
Let $f : X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$, such that

1. $f$ and $g$ are surjective;
2. $f$ and $g$ are continous.

Does this imply that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic?

It seems similar to *Bernstein's theorem* in set theory, and many of the topological properties like compactness, connectedness, etc are getting preserved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should ask a different question.
Editing an already answered question *changing the question altoghether* disrupts the question system and disregards the work which was already put in the answers below.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Apologies. I'll do that.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4138074/499096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There exists a continuous surjection $f$ between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357052/does-there-exists-a-continuous-surjection-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbr2)), and a continuous surjection $g$ between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (obvious), but they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Thanks :). A follow up question, what would happen if f and g were taken to be bijective ?

Answer (score 3):

- For a continuous surjection $S^1 \mapsto [-1,+1]$ take the first coordinate projection map $(x,y) \mapsto x$.
- For a continuous surjection $[-1,+1] \mapsto S^1$ take the map $x \mapsto (\cos(2 \pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not.

Consider $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$. The projection on any component certainly constitutes a continuous surjection $[0,1]^2 \rightarrow [0,1]$.

Conversely, there are [space filling curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), giving continuous surjections $[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]^2$.

But $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$ are **not** homeomorphic. Deleting a point in the interior of $[0,1]$ results in a disconnected space, which is **not** true, when deleting a point in the interior of $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. A follow up question, what would happen if f and g were taken to be bijective ?

Comment: That’s a good one.